# How to add mutiple entities for an attribute (iOS, Core Data)?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I want to create a one to many relationship. My setup is something like:

I have the Profile Entity,
I have the Time entity.

Every profile has a relationship to Time.

How can I define relationships, and add multiple Time entities to a single profile?

I bet it is obvious, but I can't see how to implement.

Comment: How can I set the relationship with "two arrows" in xCode 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** after posting the answer I saw your comment - to define a to-many relationship in the modeller, select the relationship and choose to-many from the options:

[image]

To populate the relationship, you can do it two ways. I am assuming your Profile entity has a to-many relationship called `times` and the inverse relationship is a to-one relationship called `profile`.

- Set the `profile` on each Time entity as you are creating them. This will automatically populate the inverse relationship (i.e. add the Time to the `times` set of the profile).
- Collect the relevant Time entities in a set and set the `times` property to this set. Again, the inverse will be automatically populated.

There is more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html). Accessor methods to add individual entities to a to-many relationship can be generated from the managed object model editor in Xcode.

Comment: If I keep adding the same Profile to every new Time I create, then the rest is managed by CoreData right?

Comment: Oh, and really, xCode creates accessors for the Profile class too, if I want to do populating by messaging Profile instance. Thanks again, my app is up and running since than.